# Is there a way to set Mixin Django Admin action parameters within the model?

Tags: python-3.x, django

So I have a working Mixin for an action that currently operates on all fields of the queryset. Instead of this, I would like the ability to specify which fields will be used by the action via the code for the Admin page.

For context, here is a brief portion of my Mixin:

```py
class MyMixin:

    def my_action(self, request, queryset):
        model_to_update = apps.get_model(
            app_label=<my_app>,
            model_name=queryset.first().__class__.__name__)
        ...
        for field in model_to_update._meta.get_fields():
             # do cool stuff with all fields
        ...
        return render(...)
```

Here is how the mixin is incorporated currently:

```py
...
@admin.register(<Model>)
class ModelAdmin(MyMixin):
    ...
    actions = ["my_action"]
    ...
```

... and what I would like to do is something along the lines of:

```py
...
@admin.register(<Model>)
class ModelAdmin(MyMixin):
    ...
    actions = [my_action(fields=['foo', 'bar',]]
    ...
```

... where `foo` and `bar` are a subset of the fields of `ModelAdmin`.

Thank you in advance for any ideas! Apologies if this has already been asked elsewhere and I'm just phrasing it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a factory function that returns an action. This doesn't require a mixin.

```
def action_factory(fields, description='some action'):
    def my_action(self, request, queryset):

        for field in fields:
             # do cool stuff with fields and queryset
             queryset.update(**{field:None})

    my_action.short_description = description
    return my_action

@admin.register(FooBar)
class FooBarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [action_factory(
        fields=['foo', 'bar'], 
        description='clear foo and bar'
    )]
```